# Sql dividing a value returned from a query with another Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I created a query that returned one value. For example here's the query:

```
Select AVG(hours_worked) FROM table1
```

I want to get this value and divide it by 7.5...I've tried:

```
(Select AVG(hours_worked) FROM table1) / 7.5
```

And I've also tried other solutions.
Any help would  be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the division in the `select`:

```
SELECT AVG(hours_worked) / 7.5
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All i had to do was this:

```
Select avg_hours/7.5 FROM (SELECT AVG(hours_worked) AS avg_hours FROM table1)
```